# Java+SQL executeQuery and return results

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm new to java and I have this problem when I'm trying to fetch data from SQL DB and show it when he logs in.

```
sql = "select nom from adherent where id_adherent=3";
try {
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "here 1");
}

try {
    if (rs.next()) {
        String sum = rs.getString("select *");
        nom.setText(" " + sum);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "here 2");
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: I doubt that `rs.getString("select *")` will have any success.

Comment: You don't need two separate try catch block, but what is your actual problem?

Comment: Just fetch data by column name (or index) like rs.getString("nom") or rs.getString(1). Also , it's best to use the ResultSet in the same try block where you fecthed the data.

Comment: rs.getString("select *"); What for is this,Is your query correct

Comment: thank's guys it work's <3 <3 <3 <3

Comment: `rs.getString("COL_NAME")` specify col name which you want

Comment: yeah i did that ts.getString(col_name) 
i wasn't know how that work , thanks guys you really save me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you:

```
sql = "select nom from adherent where id_adherent=3";

try {
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) {
        String sum = rs.getString("nom");
        nom.setText(" " + sum);
    }  
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "here 1");
}
```

Comment: yeah iv'e done just like that thank you @everyone <3

Answer (score 1):

Your don't need two try and catch, because you define your `ResultSet` in the first try block, so you can't use this, in another try, so make this instead :

```
sql = "select nom from adherent where id_adherent=3";
try {
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        String sum = rs.getString("nom");
        nom.setText(" " + sum);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "here 1");
}
```

---

If you want something perfect and far of any syntax error, or SQL Injection, you have to use the operator `?` of PreparedStatement for example :

```
sql = "select nom from adherent where id_adherent = ?";
//--------------------------------------------------^
try {
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setInt(1, id_adherent);//you can set any number in id_adherent in your case 3
    ....
```

Comment: Also, when using a PreparedStatement, it would make much more sense (and is safer) to write the sql as "select nom from adherent where id_adherent=?" and then set the parameter with pst.setInt(1, 3);

Comment: i already write something in this context @dsp_user just a moment

Comment: Yes, it seems complete now :)